# org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unable to acquire connection from the pool within configured maximum time of 60000ms

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are using neo4j neo4j-community-3.5.30. We have a java program that creates a query and inserts it using the neo4j driver session.

Since the program tries to run hundred of queries, we start getting the below error after some time.

org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unable to acquire connection from the pool within configured maximum time of 60000ms

Tried increasing the connection pool as well.

```
        Config config = Config.builder().withConnectionTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).withMaxConnectionPoolSize(3000).withMaxConnectionLifetime(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS).withMaxTransactionRetryTime(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    driver = GraphDatabase.driver( "bolt://localhost:7687",  AuthTokens.basic( "***", "****" ),config );
```

Comment: The connection pool is being closed because it is waiting for the entire update to complete. You can do something like per 10k of records  {open conn, run query/insert then close conn} then repeat until all records are consumed.

Comment: Okay, so basically, there are too many open connections already and that's why it's not able to acquire more connections from the pool. So ideally, it should be in batches. One connection for one batch (10k) and then once done, close it. Is that right @jose_bacoy ?